# Can i use if statement to switch between locations?

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart, switch-statement, mobile-development

I hope this meet all flutter developers well.

i'm working on an app and there are several issues i've been going through. here is my question.

i want to switch between selectedLocations and it will bring out forms related to the location out for users to fill.

here are the locations below in pictures and the codes follows.
[image: Scoops & Events]

```
    void switchSelectedCountry(selection) {
    events = selection;
    scoops = selection;
    setState(() {
      _selectedLocation = selection;
    });
  }

formField: FixDropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: _selectedLocation,
                      hint: Text('Select'),
                      items: <String>['Scoops', 'Events',].map((String value) {
                        return new FixDropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: new Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedLocation = newValue;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Put an `if` block in your `build` method.

Comment: show me, i've been trying that not working maybe i'm doing it wrongly

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

you can check which value has been selected in drop down and based on that you can show specific form, 
for example,

```
if(dropdownValue == 'events') Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: yearController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(
                            'year'),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
if(dropdownValue == 'Scoops') Sizebox(RETURN YOU WIDGET)
```